# Is it possible to get the sum of overall_score in this query?

Tags: php, moodle

So I have a table of links , and a table of votes for those links. So for instance, link google.co.uk has one record in the links table, and then it could have four vote records in the votes table, each with a score of -1 , 1 or 2 . I have done this query which sums the votes for each link, but is it possible to sum all the scores for all the links in the same query, so the user has a score?

```
SELECT *, SUM(v.vote_score) AS overall_score 
FROM mdl_link_critic_links l 
    JOIN mdl_link_critic_votes v on l.id = v.link_id 
WHERE l.user_id = '3' 
GROUP BY l.id
```

results are like

```
google.co.uk, user_id 3, overall_score 3
ebay.co.uk , user_id 3, overall_score 4
stackoverflow.com, user_id, 3, overall_score 10
```

and I would like to sum all the overall scores , so in this case, it would be 17

Comment: *"so in this case, it would be 17"* - You mean 16. 3, 3, 3, 4 and 3 make 16, not 17. ;-)

Comment: no, sum the field overall_score, 3 + 4 + 10 make 17 :)

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` it will give you `null, null,17`

Comment: Do you still want to see the 3 result rows or just a total

Comment: Only, so you can have more info about WITH ROLLUP: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @Rich *my duh*, hehe [*"Sorry about that Chief..."*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPwrodxghrw) ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'd like to be able to show all the link rows, with their score and then an overall score at the end.

Comment: Then @splash58 has your answer, and its so simple

Comment: Yep WITH ROLLUP does produce a record at the end with a sum of all the overall scores, that's it @splash58

Comment: I did not have doubts about that

Answer (score 0):

What about a subquery? It would look like this one more or less:

```sql
SELECT x.user_id, SUM(overall_score) AS user_score
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(v.vote_score) AS overall_score 
    FROM mdl_link_critic_links l 
    JOIN mdl_link_critic_votes v on l.id = v.link_id 
    GROUP BY l.id
) AS x
GROUP BY x.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, v.user_id, v.vote_score AS user_score, o.overall_score
FROM mdl_link_critic_links l 
JOIN mdl_link_critic_votes v ON v.link_id = l.id 
JOIN (SELECT v.link_id, SUM(v.vote_score) AS overall_score
      FROM mdl_link_critic_votes v
      GROUP BY v.link_id) o ON o.link_id = l.id
```